# Regex Notepad ++ : replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need some help to find and replace an expression using regex with Notepad++. I don't find the correct expression to find AND replace an expression.

I have a big file with a lot of

`SELECT xxx FROM xxx`

And I want to replace the `FROM xxx` with a

```
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[xxx]
```

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Search for:

```
(?<=FROM )([^ ]+)
```

Replace with:

```
[MyDatabase].[dbo].[\1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Search : SELECT (.+) FROM (.+)

Replace : FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[\2]

Answer (score 0):

Easily find this: `from\s+(\w+)`
and replace it by this: `[MyDatabase].[dbo].[\1]`
It will match any word after `from` and spaces

[image]